# redash GET request works on POSTMAN but not on axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, postman

On [redash](https://redash.io/) I have a query. It's `GET` request. On `POSTMAN` it works well.
Query example:

```
https://app.redash.io/<company name>/api/queries/<query id>/results.json?api_key=<api key>
```

But on `axios` it throws:

> Network error

And on console written:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at `https://app.redash.io/<company name>/api/queries/<query id>/results.json?api_key=<api key>` from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My `axios` default configs:

```js
import axios from 'axios/index';
import { appVersion } from '../../constants/defaultValues';

const { CancelToken } = axios;
export const source = CancelToken.source();

const api = axios.create({
    timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    headers: {
        version: appVersion,
    },
    cancelToken: source.token,
});

export default api;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not from your code. your code is right

CORS is a browser feature. Servers need to opt into CORS to allow browsers to bypass same-origin policy. Your server would not have that same restriction and be able to make requests to any server with a public API.

You can read more about [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)